# Meaning of X = X[:, 1] in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I am studying this snippet of python code. What does `X = X[:, 1]` mean in the last line?

```
def linreg(X,Y):
    # Running the linear regression
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    model = regression.linear_model.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    a = model.params[0]
    b = model.params[1]
    X = X[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
x = np.random.rand(3,2)

x
Out[37]: 
array([[ 0.03196827,  0.50048646],
       [ 0.85928802,  0.50081615],
       [ 0.11140678,  0.88828011]])

x = x[:,1]

x
Out[39]: array([ 0.50048646,  0.50081615,  0.88828011])
```

So what that line did is [sliced](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) the array, taking all rows (`:`) but keeping the second column (`1`)

Comment: No problem, glad I helped.

Comment: Your link is incorrect (it points to the Python 2.3 docs). Use [this one](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) from the `numpy` docs instead.

Comment: @MattDMo more up-to-date, I was trying to find something related to python.

Comment: The Python docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice), and are linked from the numpy ones. Both are necessary to understand what's going on in the example, as the numpy syntax is different from standard Python.

Comment: So the important takeaway is that this is numpy extension to Python, not standard Python (2 or 3) right?

Comment: For readers who find this latter even more up to date, docs are here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 14):

### Something you should know

The term you need to search for is "slice".
`x[start:end:step]` is the full form.
Here we can omit some values and it will use a default value:

- start defaults to `0`,
- end defaults to the length of the list,
- and step defaults to `1`.

And hence `x[:]` means the same as `x[0:len(x):1]`

Answer (score 9):

Meaning of X = X[:, 1] in Python is:

- X is a dataset or a array
- Say Here X have n rows and n columns
- so by doing x=x[:,1] we get all the rows in x present at index 1.

for example:

```
x = array([[0.69859393, 0.1042432 ],
   [0.55138493, 0.18639614],
   [0.27338772, 0.80351282]])

x[:,1] = array([0.1042432 , 0.18639614, 0.80351282])
```

Answer (score 4):

It is like you are specifying the axis. Consider the starting column as 0 then as you go through 1,2 and so on.

The syntax is `x[row_index,column_index]`

You can also specify a range of row values as per your need in `row_index`, eg:`1:13` extracts first 13 rows along with whatever specified in the column

Comment: since index starts at 0, 1:13 only extracts12 rows, starting on the 2nd element. For extract first 13 rows,you should use the expression 0:13.

Answer (score 3):

x[:,1] this is 2d slicing, here x[row_index, column_index]